# How to submit form with HTML intact

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've searched the web and not found anything relevant.

I'm trying to submit HTML, via hidden input form, to a PDF generator. But when I submit all `&nbsp;` are being stripped.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < receipts.length; i++) {
    params.receiptHtmls[i] = receipts[i].receiptHtml.replace("width=device-width, initial-scale=1", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    params.receiptHtmls[i] = receipts[i].receiptHtml.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

var disp = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');

if (disp && disp.search('attachment') !== -1) {
    var form = $('<form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="' + url + '">');

    $.each(params.receiptHtmls, function(k, v) {
        form.append($('<input type="hidden"name="receiptHtmls[]" value="' + v + '">'));
    });

    $.each(params.names, function(k, v) {
        form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="names[]" value="' + v + '">'));

    });

    $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

When I step through the code it's evident that the `&nsps;` are being stripped before form submit.

Any idea why this is happening and what I could do to prevent it?

Comment: Check out the String object, specifically the method fromCharCode(), if you find the unicode for &nsps; online somewhere, you should be able to pass in String.fromCharCode(unicodeNumber), if I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that anyone should run into this.

The solution ended up being that we need to use `document.createElement("input");` to create the inputs and then `setAttribute('type', 'hidden')`, ect.

`form.append($('<input type="hidden"name="receiptHtmls[]" value="' + v + '">'));` caused the issue every time.